How to remove a file from root directory in macOS?
On my Mac (macOS Sonoma 14.5), I have created a symlink file in the root directory (/) a long time ago. I just noticed that it must have been moved from Mac to Mac by the Migration Assistant, so that it is still there, but now protected in a way that I cannot remove it any more.
I tried

boot to recovery mode
disable SIP (csrutil disable)
boot back into macOS

Trying to remove the symlink file, this got refused because the file system is read-only. So I tried
sudo mount -uw /

which I had found somewhere on the web, but then got
mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Permission denied
mount: / failed with 66

In recovery mode, the symlink is not visible, so I can't do anything from there. It seems it's merged somehow into the root directory only when booting into macOS, but I don't know where it comes from then.
I'm stuck there - what else can I do to get rid of the old symlink file?

Note that there are similar questions, but they are old and their answers don't seem to  work any more on a modern sealed macOS boot volume, so I decided to ask a new question.

What version of macOS? Why not do an erase install to get a clean macOS rather than migrating from a legacy standpoint? Also, SIP only prevents the running OS from modifying itself, boot to recovery and you should be fine to delete.

Edit the file /etc/synthetic.conf and remove the entry for the link you created, or just delete the file, then reboot.

@bmike I've update my questions with the macOS version. Wrt your other question, Apple's Migration Assistant is one of the most useful and time-saving utilities in macOS, and it has always worked without problems, so I don't see a reason to not use it and do everything manually instead. boot to recovery and you should be fine to delete – as explained in my question, the symlink isn't there in recovery mode.

@LincD. Thanks, I didn't know about /etc/synthetic.conf, and this indeed solved it. I was able to this from within the normal macOS, just had to reboot after that. Will you add that as an answer, perhaps with some background info, so I can happily accept it?

The macOS Setup Assistant automatically created a "synthetic link" to replace the one it found in the read-only root directory. The configuration is contained in the file /etc/synthetic.conf. You can either delete that file (if you have no other need for it), or edit it to remove the unwanted entry. For more details, see the man page synthetic.conf(5).

A reboot was required to actually have the symlink removed after that.
